# Trouble moving info from an array to another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Disclaimer: New to Javascript

I am trying to create a 2D array and move it to another sheet, but cannot get the values to go onto the sheet. It runs, but doesn't add anything and I can't find anything regarding my issue.

Don't mind the switch case or anything, only the first and last part of my code are what I need help on.

```
function infoTransfer()
{

var actveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var byName = actveSheet.getSheetByName("New Item Input Sheet");
var infoCols = byName.getDataRange().getNumColumns();
var infoRange = byName.getDataRange().getNumRows();

var rowData = [];
for (var a = 1; a < infoRange; a++)
{
  var colData = [];
  for (var b = 2; b < infoCols; b++)
  {
    colData.push(b);
  }
  rowData.push(colData);

  rowData[[a][b]] = byName.getRange(a + 1, b + 1, infoRange, infoCols);   
}

var itemsAddedSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID');
var warehouseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID');
var monthValue = byName.getRange('A2').getValue();

switch (monthValue)
{
  case "January":
    var sheet = itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('January');
    var monthSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('January');
    var archiveSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
    break;
  case "February":
    var sheet = itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('February');
    var monthSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('February');
    var archiveSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
    break;
  case "March":
    var sheet = itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('March');
    var monthSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('March');
    var archiveSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
    break;
  case "April":
    var sheet = itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('April');
    var monthSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('April');
    var archiveSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
    break;
  case "May":
    var sheet = itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('May');
    var monthSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('May');
    var archiveSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
    break;      
  case "June":
    var sheet = itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('June');
    var monthSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('June');
    var archiveSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
    break;      
  case "July":
    var sheet = itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('July');
    var monthSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('July');
    var archiveSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
    break;      
  case "August":
    var sheet = itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('August');
    var sheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('August');
    var archiveSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
    break;      
  case "September":
    var sheet = itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('September');
    var monthSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('September');
    var archiveSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
    break;     
  case "October":
    var sheet = itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('October');
    var monthSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('October');
    var archiveSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
    break;      
  case "November":
    var sheet = itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('November');
    var monthSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('November');
    var archiveSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
    break;      
  default:
    var sheet = itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('December');
    var monthSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('December');
   var archiveSheet = warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
    break;      
}

for (var a = 1; a < infoRange; a++)
{
  for (var b = 2; b < infoCols; b++)
  {
    colData.push(b);
  }
  rowData.push(colData);

  sheet.getRange(a + 1, b + 1, infoRange, infoCols).setValues(rowData[[a][b]].getValues());
  sheet.getRange(2, 11, infoRange - 1, 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
}
}
```

Comment: can you duplicate the spreadsheet and share it? it's just too large to debug. but this ` rowData[[a][b]] = byName.getRange(a + 1, b + 1, infoRange, infoCols);` doesnt look right

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with your `rowData[[a][b]]` notation. It should be in this format instead `tableData[rowIndex][columnIndex]`, so likely `rowData[a][b]`.

Comment: New Item Input Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VxogEhDmweT7gZBE0FcPuQJMqbFRCrY34LPOMcCtROg/edit#gid=0 -- Items Added Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1byb0Ft7poB66HlX8mZLnd_SIF2V5o9G6O8gdhweTe70/edit#gid=0

Comment: @NikkoKhresna - I pasted the links and allowed anyone with access to the links the power to edit the sheet

Comment: Could you explain why @Cooper answer didn't work out? It seems is doing the right ting at copying the range over the other sheet, but you didn't comment on that part. Also you say that you don't need help with the `if` statement but there is no `if` in the whole snippet, what did you mean? Have you looked at the last part of the code where he changed the `for` nested loop. I think that is the problem with your code.

Comment: @Raserhin - Cooper's answer did work. I was busy over the weekend and on Friday afternoon and I did not come back to this page until today. BTW, I did not post ALL the code I was working on, just the part I needed help with, which is why you don't see an if statement anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what your looking for?

```
function infoTransfer() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('New Item Input Sheet');
  const vs=sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  const itemsAddedSheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID');
  const warehouseSheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID');
  const monthValue=byName.getRange('A2').getValue();
  switch (monthValue){
    case "January":
      var sheet=itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('January');
      var monthSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('January');
      var archiveSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
      break;
    case "February":
      var sheet=itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('February');
      var monthSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('February');
      var archiveSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
      break;
    case "March":
      var sheet=itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('March');
      var monthSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('March');
      var archiveSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
      break;
    case "April":
      var sheet=itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('April');
      var monthSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('April');
      var archiveSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
      break;
    case "May":
      var sheet=itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('May');
      var monthSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('May');
      var archiveSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
      break;      
    case "June":
      var sheet=itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('June');
      var monthSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('June');
      var archiveSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
      break;      
    case "July":
      var sheet=itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('July');
      var monthSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('July');
      var archiveSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
      break;      
    case "August":
      var sheet=itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('August');
      var sheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('August');
      var archiveSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
      break;      
    case "September":
      var sheet=itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('September');
      var monthSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('September');
      var archiveSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
      break;     
    case "October":
      var sheet=itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('October');
      var monthSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('October');
      var archiveSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
      break;      
    case "November":
      var sheet=itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('November');
      var monthSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('November');
      var archiveSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
      break;      
    default:
      var sheet=itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName('December');
      var monthSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('December');
      var archiveSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
      break;      
  }
  sheet.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  sheet.getRange(2, 11, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
}
```

It's not clear what you wish to do with monthSheet and archiveSheet.

I would probably consider doing it this way:

```
function infoTransfer() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('New Item Input Sheet');
  const vs=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const itemsAddedSheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID');
  const warehouseSheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID');
  const monthValue=byName.getRange('A2').getValue();
  const sheet=itemsAddedSheet.getSheetByName(monthValue);
  const monthSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName(monthValue);
  const archiveSheet=warehouseSheet.getSheetByName('Archive 2020');
  sheet.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  sheet.getRange(2, 11, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Not ALL of the code is pasted which is why archiveSheet isn't anywhere to be found in there. I excluded it because it wasn't essential to the question. However, what I want to do with archiveSheet is add a new row if a value in itemsAddedSheet equals yes, which is why I need the 2D array so that I can pull specific data and paste it into archiveSheet and itemsAddedSheet. I don't need help with the if statement, just getting the array to paste on the itemsAddedSheet from the New Item Input Sheet. Does that help answer to question more thoroughly?